# D3: Grayscale image display driven by 2D array data

Tags: javascript, json, svg, d3.js, heatmap

Does anybody know how to display a greyscale image, i.e. a 2-D array of pixel intensities,using d3? I can't seem to find any examples of it anywhere, is it going to be tricky? Any help / links / pointers appreciated!

Comment: Yeah, something along those lines. I see a few links to d3 heatmaps,no plain images though so far. I'm slightly surprised. . .

Comment: What do you mean by "plain image"?

Comment: Found an example here: http://bl.ocks.org/3074470

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If just want to display an image, use the [image element](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/struct.html#ImageElement) and the "xlink:href" attribute. For example:

```
svg.append("image")
    .attr("xlink:href", "my.png")
    .attr("width", 960)
    .attr("height", 500);
```

If you want to colorize a grayscale image, then see this [colorized heightmap example](http://bl.ocks.org/3289530) which uses quantiles to create a diverging color scale, and with HCL interpolation for better perception:

[image: colorized heightmap]

If you have your data in some other representation, these examples might be useful:

- [heatmap from CSV using SVG rect elements](http://bl.ocks.org/3202354)
- [heatmap from JSON using Canvas](http://bl.ocks.org/3074470)

Lastly, if you have individual samples rather than a precomputed 2D histogram, you’ll need to bin the data before generating one of the above heatmaps.

Comment: Very cool, thanks for the info. The heightmap is a nice example of what I was aiming gor. Basically I have a 2-d python array that I am working with. Thanks for providing d3 Michael!

Comment: One question, why is the image at http://bl.ocks.org/3074470 smooth and not too pixelated.

Comment: Please mark this question as accepted if I have answered your question. For your second question, the image is smooth because the browser resamples the canvas (like any other image) when it is displayed at non-native resolution. You may be able to control this behavior via the [image-rendering](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Image-rendering) style property.